# How to bring link to layer on top of tr/row?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a table which looks like this:

```
<table id="display">
    <tr class="trigger">
        <td>Info here</td>
        <td><a href="example.com">Link here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've got  a jQuery script running "onclick" on `trigger`, so when `trigger` is clicked, it performs an action. The problem with this is that the `<a href>` functionality is lost because the tr is layered on top. Click on the link will just trigger the `trigger` action, not the link action.

Is there a way I can bring this link to ignore the other functionality and perform native? I've tried setting the `a` to `z-index: 9999;` as well as `position: absolute;` but neither solved the issue.

The jQuery script looks like this (its a simple tree view):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.trigger").click(function () {
       $(this).next().animate({
          height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'
        }, "fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("opened");
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Instead of using the `$(this)` selector twice in a row you can chain the function calls: `$(this).next().animate({height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'}, "fast").toggleClass("opened");`

Comment: @Jasper: the `toggleClass()` will call on the `.next()` object, not on the original. You'll need to place `.toggleClass()` *before* `.next()`.

Comment: @Blender Or use `.end()` after the `.animate()` function call, good catch: `$(this).next().animate({height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'}, "fast").end().toggleClass("opened");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the event from propagating to the parent element:

```
$("tr.trigger a").click(function(e) {
  // Your code

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `return false` == `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` inside a jQuery event handler? Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Jasper, it's true but. Blender has set `e.stopPropagation` for an `a` tag, and John for `tr` tag.

Comment: @welldan97 Good call I didn't catch that.